# MySQl - Not able to get the NULL values from "ans_desc" column according to "ques_id" column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ques_id,ans_desc
FROM answer
ORDER BY ans_desc
HAVING ans_desc=0
```

Comment: Note that `null` and 0 are not the same thing. 0 is a definite value somewhere between 1 and -1. `null` means that the value of the column is **undefined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ans_desc IS NULL` predicate in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ques_id, ans_desc 
FROM answer 
WHERE ans_desc = 0 OR ans_desc IS NULL
ORDER BY ans_desc ;
```

This will give you only those that have either `0` or `NULL` values in the `ans_desc` column.

The `WHERE ans_desc = 0` alone won't give the `NULL` values.

Comment: but this is returning all the values from "ans_desc" column with the NULL values too.

Comment: @user2189793 Then don't select it `SELECT ques_id 
FROM answer 
WHERE ans_desc = 0 OR ans_desc IS NULL
ORDER BY ans_desc ;`

Comment: This is showing all the "ques_id"... i need to know which of the "ques_id" doesn't have "ans_desc" column containing nothing

Comment: @user2189793 - Then use `NOT NULL`: `SELECT ques_id FROM answer WHERE ans_desc = 0 OR ans_desc IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ans_desc ;`

Answer (score 0):

`0` is different from `NULL` and different from empty

```
SELECT ques_id,ans_desc
FROM answer
WHERE ISNULL(ans_desc) OR ans_desc = ''
ORDER BY ans_desc
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING ans_desc IS NULL OR ans_desc = '' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: i edited the post, tell me if it's OK now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need 'order by ans_desc' when you need to select only the rows with NULL values.

You should do something like:

```
SELECT ques_id as `question`, ans_desc as `answer`
FROM answer
WHERE ans_desc is NULL;
```

Advantage of this query is that it doesn't use filesort.

See output of explain for the query you are using to know more.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The response to this query was - MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: what do you want to select from this table? The question is not very clear. what I answered here is perhaps a direction. You need to replace the requirement of the ans_desc in the where clause. For instance if you want to select question_id which have no/blank answer, You'd like to execute: 
`(SELECT ques_id as \`question\`, ans_desc as \`answer\`
FROM answer
WHERE ans_desc is NULL or ans_desc = "";)`